# Google Docs, link to dynamic range from Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

Following this guide, I am able to link data from my Google Sheet into my Google Doc.

https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308662?hl=en

Is there a way to have range size update automatically when the table shrinks and grows?

Comment: I think you could link to a named range, and update that named range programmatically via Apps Script via [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger. What actions would cause the table to shrink and grow? And how what's part of the table and what's not would be identified?

Comment: @Iamblichus - this sounds like a workable solution.  The table is generated from Jira Addon to Google-Docs.  My workflows in the past are heavily Office360 based, so evaluating a move over to Google Docs.   As for shrinking and growing, it's based on the number of Jira issues that match particular criteria.

Comment: Well, if the table edits are programmatic and not manual, the solution I suggested cannot work, since `onEdit` only works for user edits. The other option would be to use a time-driven trigger. With this, the range could be updated periodically (with the maximum frequency being each minute). Would that be ok? Also, are the values actually written to the spreadsheet, or is this populated via a formula?

Comment: @Iamblichus, the values are written to the spreadsheet.   How would time-driven-trigger work when updating from Google-doc.   Do time driven-triggers just update when the sheet is in focus/use?   It sounds like the only way is a programmatic solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

1. Create a new named range that includes the current range of the table (ref: [Name a range of cells](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/63175)).
2. Link that named range to your desired location, using [Link to data in a spreadsheet](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308662).
3. On your spreadsheet, click `Tools > Script editor` to open a bound script, and copy the following code. This function retrieves your desired named range and updates it with the current dimensions of your table:

```
const SHEET_NAME = "Sheet1"; // Change according to your preferences
const NAMED_RANGE_NAME = "MY_RANGE"; // Change according to your preferences

function updateNamedRange() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  const namedRanges = ss.getNamedRanges();
  const namedRange = namedRanges.find(namedRange => namedRange.getName() === NAMED_RANGE_NAME);
  const range = sheet.getRange("A1").getDataRegion();
  namedRange.setRange(range);
}
```

4. Install a [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) which will fire `updateNamedRange` with the specified periodicity. You can do that manually (following [these steps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually)), or programatically. In order to install this programmatically, copy and run a function like this once:

```
function installTimeTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("updateNamedRange")
  .timeBased()
  .everyMinutes(1)
  .create();
}
```

#### Note:

- The previous sample is using [everyMinutes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#everyminutesn) with the parameter set to 1, so the range will be updated every minute. You can find methods for alternative frequencies [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder).
- In the sample above, the table is in a sheet named `Sheet1`, with a named range title `MY_RANGE`, and it starts at cell `A1`. Change all those in your spreadsheet if that's not your case.
- I'm assuming you already know how to link named ranges.

Comment: Very Helpful,  just to note - getDataRegion();  is very powerful, I had been minding to forEach over all the rows, but that function is excellent.  It also handles orphaned cels as long as there is some data in the previous row.  Further, I've tied my script to a button rather than a timed trigger as there is a process that takes place to change the source data.